Similar matrices with entries in $p$-adic numbers
It is known that

Given a rational matrix  $Q$, if the characteristic equation of $Q$ has integral coefficients, then  $Q$  is similar ( over $ \mathbb Q$ ) to a matrix with integral entries.

Do we have a similar result for matrices with entries in $\mathbb{Q}_p$? i.e. if the characteristic polynomial of $Q \in GL_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ have coefficients in $\mathbb Z_p$, then Q is similar to a matrix with entries in $\mathbb{Z}_p$?
I am not sure if this has been studied before, any ideas/references would be really appreciated.

Yes, and in fact more generally if $R$ is a unique factorization domain and $F = Frac(R)$, then any matrix over $F$ whose characteristic polynomial is in $R$ is similar over $F$ to a matrix over $R$.
The proof I have in mind uses rational canonical form. In short, over a general field $F$, similarity classes of $n \times n$ matrices $A$ are in bijection with sequences of polynomials $f_1,\ldots, f_k \in F[x]$ such that $f_1 \mid f_2 \mid \cdots \mid f_k$ and $\deg f_1 + \cdots + \deg f_k = n$.
The corresponding matrix is block diagonal, and the blocks are companion matrices for the $f_i$. The polynomials $f_1,\ldots, f_k$ are the invariant factors of the matrix $A$. The characteristic polynomial of $A$ turns out to be the product of the invariant factors $f_1\cdots f_k$ (this is a nice exercise).
Now suppose $F = Frac(R)$ for $R$ a unique factorization domain and the characteristic polynomial of $A$ lies in $R[x]$. Then the invariant factors $f_1,\cdots, f_k$ are all monic and their product is the characteristic polynomial, so by Gauss' Lemma, all of the $f_i$ actually have coefficients in $R$. Then the companion matrices for the $f_i$ have entries in $R$, so $A$ is similar to a matrix defined over $R$.
